# Gcd and update query

Tags: algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

i have a sequence of numbers A[0] to A[n-1].

there can be 2 possible queries.

query 1 : gcd i j : Calculate gcd of all nos. A[k] such that i<=k<=j.

query 2 : update i j : change A[i] to j

eg.

```
gcd 2 4
gcd 1 5
update 2 3
gcd 2 4
update 4 1
gcd 3 6
```

What is the fastest algorithm to do this ?

Comment: to do what exactly? find gcd?

Comment: there are two types of queries. for each query i need to give the corresponding answer. @AliAmiri

Comment: For swap there is a obvious O(1) answer, temp = a[i], a[i] = a[j] , a[j] = temp. but I'm currently thinking about fastest way for GCD.

Comment: I'm sorry second query is not even swap, just a[i] = a[j] is enough. but about first query, is there any condition?

Comment: No condition. I have to just calculate gcd. everytime finding gcd seems a bad idea . dp may be used. but don't know how.

Comment: take a look at my solution here : http://pastebin.com/LCSAVptZ because it wasnot final I didnot post it as an answer :)

Comment: but what's its use ? how can I answer my question with this ?

Comment: take some time to think about how that may help you :)

Comment: you can do it using a segment tree each query will be answered in O(logn)

Comment: gcd (a1, a2, a3 ... an) = gcd (a1, gcd (a2, a3 ... an)). So you can reduce the problem to finding the gcd of two numbers, and repeating this in a loop or through recursion. There is an efficient algorithm (Euclid) for calculating the gcd of two numbers, see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor.

Comment: Doesn't it takes O(n) time to calculate gcd of a1,.......,an? complexity must be lower than O(n) for each query.

Answer (score 0):

Good question,

the first idea that comes into mind is to use segment trees. If you are not familiar with segment trees here is very useful tutorial for that. On each node we can keep gcd of numbers in segment which is covered by that node. So we will need to consider logn number of nodes for each update query, and for second query we can just return value which is kept in the root node. For each node we will need to count gcd of its two children values, so update query needs O((logn)^2) time and the second query will need O(1) time.

Here is the link for segment trees:
https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/#Segment_Trees

Comment: I know segment trees. What made me inquisitive was that if there is any faster technique for this :P

Comment: Faster than O(logn), you mean O(1)? Maybe for quantum computers